# before Google Access token expiration time

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-docs, access-token

I am integrating file uploading direct on google drive in php .But I know that access token expiration time is 1 hour and that is associated with a email id. If user logout before 1 hour how to know that user logged out from google or not. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#auth-example

You can use the function "checkAuth()" to verify that the user is still logged in.